# Python SQLite3 - Loop to Populate First Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

With Python3 I am trying to read in a text file and populate the first column of an SQLite3 table.  The for-loop and execute combination is providing errors and I don't quite know what's going wrong.

```
import sqlite3
WORDLIST = 'words.txt'   #list of words only

con = sqlite3.connect('dict.db')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dict')
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE dict(word text, part text, definition text)')
con.commit()

with open(WORDLIST,'r') as dictionary:
    for each_word in dictionary:
        print(each_word)
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO rainbow_table VALUES (?)',(each_word,))
```

The input file words.txt is pretty simple

```
Cat
Bruno
Movie
Truth
```

I haven't yet been able to correct the run-time error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dictdb.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dict_table VALUES (?)',(each_word,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table dict_table has 3 columns but 1 values were      supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the database is expecting 3 values to be inserted into the 3 columns that your table has since you did not specify which columns you wanted to insert into. According to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp), if you want to insert only one of the three values, you have to specify which column you want with the following syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO dict_table (word_text) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: @CL. Whoops, I totally derped on that. Thanks. I removed it from my answer.